# How to fix this code?

Tags: java

```
public static int guess (int numberOfGuesses, int secretNumber) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int n = 1; n <= numberOfGuesses; n++){
      System.out.println("Guess "+n+" of "+numberOfGuesses+":");
      int userNumber = sc.nextInt();
      if(userNumber == secretNumber){
        return n;       
      }
      while(userNumber > secretNumber){
        System.out.println("The guess is too big");
      }
      while(userNumber < secretNumber){
        System.out.println("The guess is too small");
      }
       while(userNumber > 100){
        System.out.println("The number "+userNumber+" is not valid. ");
       }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This syntax is not valid. Look at your `if{} return n; else {}`

Comment: Revision 3 changed the code, so rolled back to rev 2....

Comment: "How to fix this code?"... well, I think rewriting it in a syntactically and logically sound manner sounds like a plan. This doesn't compile, and it doesn't really resemble anything imperative. You should probably read some tutorials or so, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. You don't have to break from the loop when the numbers match. You simply return `n`, as you required. If the loop exits without the `secretNumber` being found, you return `-1`.

```
public static int guess (int numberOfGuesses, int secretNumber) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int n = 1; n <= numberOfGuesses; n++){
        System.out.println("Guess "+n+" of "+numberOfGuesses+":");
        int userNumber = sc.nextInt();

        if(userNumber == secretNumber){
            return n;       
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

BTW, the code would make more sense if you give the user some hints that would help them guess the secret number.

Comment: wow I can't believe it. Could you explain to me why that is? Im trying to learn the language. Thank you.

Comment: @Rawrqqplz What don't you understand? You can exit a for loop in one of several ways - 1. when the condition becomes false 2. by calling `break` 3. by returning from the method that contains the loop (calling `return something;`). Since you wish to exit the loop and return n at the same time, the simplest thing to do is `return n;`.

Comment: How would I be able to incorporate hints such as if the userNumber is higher than the secretNumber display "your number is too high" and things like that? Because I wouldn't have anything to return for the method right? and I would need to return something?

Comment: @Rawrqqplz This has nothing to do with the return value of the method. While you are inside the loop, you can check if the number is too high, and print "your number is too high".

Comment: is that possible by using a while or do while statement?

Comment: @Rawrqqplz It's possible regardless of whether you are using a while loop or a for loop.

Comment: I always end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: @Rawrqqplz I'll have to see the code that gives infinite loop in order to help.

Comment: @Rawrqqplz replace the `while`s with `if`s. You don't need nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

It is cleaner to close the `Scanner` after using it, so I would do something like this :

```
public static int guess(int numberOfGuesses, int secretNumber) {
        Scanner sc     = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userNumber = secretNumber / 2;
        boolean found  = false;
        int tries;
        for (tries = 0 ; tries <= numberOfGuesses && !found ; tries++) {
            userNumber = sc.nextInt();
            found      = secretNumber == userNumber;
        }
        sc.close();
        return found ? tries : -1;
    }
```